# Windows Runtime raise events from other library

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

I have a library A that has some events and I'm using this library inside my own library B, and then i have my Windows Runtime application that has the reference only to library B.

When an event is raised from the library A I'd like to catch this event in my Windows Runtime Application project.

There is some way to do that?

Comment: Why not referencing Library A?

Comment: Because by app design it is not correct because we want to separate the layers, but i'm thinking on create the same event in Library B and raising them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either reference library A in your Windows Runtime application, as it is needed by the library B.

Or you could wrap the Events inside of B. Take a look here:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Register at B
        BLibClass.BEvent += MyMethod;

        // Something triggers A
        BLibClass.ATrigger();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void MyMethod()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Something happeneds!");
    }
}
```

Here is the A library:

```
public class ALibClass
{
    public delegate void HandleAEvent();

    public static event HandleAEvent AEvent;

    public static void ATrigger()
    {
        AEvent();
    }
}
```

Here is the B library:

```
public class BLibClass
{
    public delegate void HandleBEvent();

    public static event HandleBEvent BEvent;

    private static void WhenAHappens()
    {
        BEvent();
    }

    static BLibClass()
    {
        ALibClass.AEvent += WhenAHappens;
    }

    public static void ATrigger()
    {
        ALibClass.ATrigger();
    }
}
```

Comment: i think is the only way, i was looking to something more elegant, but i am not able to find it